# JavaScript runs in Firefox Scratchpad, but not when loaded with the HTML

Tags: javascript, events

My question is similar to others, but as the answers vary so much depending on how the code is first setup, I still haven't found a suitable answer to my question. Let me take you through the steps I take to try to run my JavaScript.

I open a new tab in my browser, press "Ctrl + O" to bring up the file explorer, then open the html file that links to the JavaScript. The code just never executes from the file; it'll only run if I run it from Scratchpad.

How do I get my JavaScript to run from the "script.js" file without having to copy it into Scratchpad?

```js
function autocomplete(inp) {

  if (inp) {
    /*execute a function when someone writes in the text field:*/
    inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      console.log("We have input! - " + inp.value);
    });
    /*execute a function presses a key on the keyboard:*/
    inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
      console.log("We have keydown! - " + e.keyCode);
    });
  }


}

// Run autocomplete when there is imput
autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"));
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <title>Autocomplete Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      <h2>Input Tester</h2>
      <p>Enter text into the field to test</p>

      <form class="autocomplete" autocomplete="off">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder=" Search Hotels">

          <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
          <button type="button">Search</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

**Note:** This runs without issue on Stackoverflow. The error shows best when loading from a file you made (in a code editor of your choice), into your browser. I'm using the Atom code editor, in case anyone finds it relevant.

Comment: Did you look in your browser console? It'll tell you the problem. (you're not waiting for the document to be parsed before trying to add a listener to an element that doesn't exist yet. give your script tag the `defer` attribute)

Comment: @CertainPerformance -  I checked the console for errors. I guess I should have checked to see what order the code was being executed in. The `defer` attribute worked perfectly! Which is weird, considering that I tried `window.onload` several ways unsuccessfully. Could you change your comment into an answer, so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Script tags *block* by default; the browser waits for the script to finish executing before continuing to parse more HTML below it. So, at the time `<script src="script.js"...` runs, the document has not been populated yet.

Either:

(1) Give the script tag a `defer` attribute (preferred):

```
<script src="script.js" defer type="text/javascript"></script>
```

(2) Wrap the whole script in a DOMContentLoaded listener:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"));
});
```

(3) Move your script to the end of the body:

```
  </div>
  <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a better practice to place your link to JavaScript files just before closing the `<body>` tag so that You have your page loaded and then you can then get reference to it from your JavaScript.

Try this,

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Autocomplete Test</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      <div>
        <h2>Input Tester</h2>
        <p>Enter text into the field to test</p>

        <form class="autocomplete" autocomplete="off">
          <div class="wrapper">
            <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder=" Search Hotels">

            <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
            <button type="button">Search</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>

    </div>
    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: IMO, scripts, being information about *how to interact with the content*, rather than being content themselves, much more semantically belong in the header than in the `body`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance--Okay, That was helpful, I really appreciate your comment.